# check_snmp return OK or CRITICAL based on condition

Tags: parameters, snmp, nagios, threshold

I have the following service for monitoring a variable:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       Colonnina1
        service_description             FLOODING_GreenEnergy_V1
        check_command                check_snmp!enterprises.ucdavis.extTable.extEntry.extOutput.11
}
```

Now I would like that the parameter `enterprises.ucdavis.extTable.extEntry.extOutput.11` (let's call it STATE) is comparad with a variable, say `ALARM`. If `STATE==ALARM` I want the service in a critical state, otherwise in a OK state. 
How can I modify the define service above in order to get that?

Comment: same situation here! did you find a way to compare values?

Comment: I'm not sre this counts as a programming question. Meanwhile, there are 891 questions tagged [Nagios on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nagios), so maybe this question belongs there?